# How does the number of invitations work?

Tags: ingress

I see that my unused invites increment every so often, but it seems that the frequency and number of increment is totally random. Is there some kind of explanation as to how invitations are increased?

- Is there a limit for how many unused invitations I can have?

  - How often does my number of unused invitations increase?
  - How does the game determine how many new unused invitations do I get each increment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, invites are remnants of the time when Ingress was in beta, which is not the case anymore. At that time you would need an invite to play the game, or to get your friends playing.
From the Ingress support centre, on the page concerning [Recruiting new Agents](https://support.ingress.com/hc/en-us/articles/206605138-Recruit-other-Agents):

> The NIA occasionally grants Agents invites to recruit new players and
>   advance their faction's cause.

But there's no indication of frequency, nor of a limit (I personnally have more than 300).

Niantic does not communicate a lot about how Ingress works, or about its deepest game mechanics. Everything outside Official support is derived by players. [This post on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Ingress/comments/2s23wi/how_do_i_get_more_invites/) is the closest post I found about that subject.

By the way, I know this is slightly off topic, but the only advantage right now to send invites is to get the "Recruiter" badge (plus the fact that the player needs to reach level 3 to confirm it).